# Slurm job array pulling parameter set from .txt file and using parameters as objects in Rscript

Tags: r, slurm

I am currently trying to run a stochastic simulation in R using changing parameters by submitting a slurm array job to HPC. I have stored the parameters in a .txt file where each line contains the parameter iteration to be set as individual objects in R before running simulation (e.g. Line1: a=5,b=10,c=0.75,d="SL",e=1; Line2:a=5,b=10,c=0.5,d="TL",e=5; etc...). Therefore, for $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID in R, object 'a' must be 5, object 'b' must be 10, etc. I am looking for some assistance on:

How to assign each parameter set corresponding to the $SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID and setting those parameter sets as objects in R before running script.

Then I am looking to export/save a .csv of each array task doing something like write.csv(out, paste0("out",$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID,".csv")).

I hope this is enough information. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the lines of the parameters.txt file into an array and use `` to index this array and pass the data as an argument to the R script.

The basic bash script to call the `sbatch` run:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
#SBATCH --array=0-1 #adjust to your number of lines in parameters.txt

while IFS= read -r; do
  parameters+=("$REPLY")
done < "parameters.txt"

srun Rscript "calculation.R" "${parameters[SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}"
```

The `parameters.txt`:

```
a=5,b=10,c=0.75,d="SL",e=1
a=5,b=10,c=0.5,d="TL",e=5
```

The basic `calculation.R` script (here, most work is to parse the arguments):

```
# read in arguments
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)

# split into different variables
all_vars <- read.table(text = args[1], sep = ",")
colnames(all_vars) <- unlist(lapply(seq_len(ncol(all_vars)), function(i) {
  regmatches(all_vars[, i], regexpr(".*(?==)", all_vars[, i], perl = TRUE))
}))

for (i in seq_len(ncol(all_vars))) {
  all_vars[, i] <- regmatches(all_vars[, i], regexpr("(?<==).*", all_vars[, i], perl = TRUE))
}

all_vars$a <- as.numeric(all_vars$a)
all_vars$b <- as.numeric(all_vars$b)
all_vars$c <- as.numeric(all_vars$c)
all_vars$e <- as.numeric(all_vars$e)

# do calculation

# save
slurm_array_id <- Sys.getenv("SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID")
write.csv(out, paste0("out", slurm_array_id, ".csv"))
```

It would be probably easier to store the parameters in a csv file with headers, so you have to do less parsing.